# How to write Vue.js v-for

Tags: vue.js

I am not getting the desired output for my Vue.js program.
Could anyone review the code and help me to modify.

My Code:

```
  data: {
    hotels: [
      {
        "name": "hotel A",
        "facilities": []
      },
      {
        "name": "hotel B",
        "facilities": [
          "restaurant",
          "lounge",
          "wi-fi"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "hotel C",
        "facilities": [
          "wi-fi"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
<p v-for="hotel in hotels">
<span v-if="hotel.facilities.indexOf('restaurant') !== -1">{{ hotel.name }}/span>
<span v-if="hotel.facilities.indexOf('wi-fi') !== -1">{{ hotel.name }}</span>
</p>
```

Current output:

```
<p><!----> <!----></p>
<p><span>hotel B</span> <span>hotel B</span></p>
<p><!----> <span>hotel C</span></p>
```

Desired output:

```
<p>
<span>hotel B</span>
<span>hotel B</span>
<span>hotel C</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the v-for will repeat for each occurrence of hotel in your array, creating 3 times the `<p>`

To create `<p>` only one time you should put your code into a `<template>` tag nested inside the `<p>` tag.

Example:

```
<p>
  <template v-for="hotel in hotels">
    <span v-if="hotel.facilities.indexOf('restaurant') !== -1">{{ hotel.name }}/span>
    <span v-if="hotel.facilities.indexOf('wi-fi') !== -1">{{ hotel.name }}</span>
  </template>
</p>
```

Comment: I was able to get the desired output by both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>
  <span v-for="hotel in hotels">
    <template v-if="hotel.facilities.indexOf('restaurant') !== -1">{{ hotel.name }}/template >
    <template v-if="hotel.facilities.indexOf('wi-fi') !== -1">{{ hotel.name }}</template >
  </span>
</p>
```